# How I can slide the custom keyboard down with back button and bytouching the layout

Tags: android, keyboard

Hi I have a custom keyboard or Numpad I have 2 problems that I don't know how to do it  ............  when i press back button the app closes I want to slide the keyboard down at first when  pressing the back button and I want same thing if I click on my layout (white)(look at the pic u will understand)

[image]

```
public class BasicOnKeyboardActionListener implements OnKeyboardActionListener {

private Activity mTargetActivity;


public BasicOnKeyboardActionListener(Activity targetActivity) {
    mTargetActivity = targetActivity;
}

@Override
public void swipeUp() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void swipeRight() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void swipeLeft() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void swipeDown() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onText(CharSequence text) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onPress(int primaryCode) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
    long eventTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    KeyEvent event = new KeyEvent(eventTime, eventTime,
            KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, primaryCode, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            KeyEvent.FLAG_SOFT_KEYBOARD | KeyEvent.FLAG_KEEP_TOUCH_MODE);

    mTargetActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

CustomKeyboardView.class

```
public class CustomKeyboardView extends KeyboardView {

public CustomKeyboardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public void showWithAnimation(Animation animation) {
    animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    setAnimation(animation);
}
```

KeyboardWidgetTutorialActivity.class

```
public class KeyboardWidgetTutorialActivity extends Activity {

private CustomKeyboardView mKeyboardView;
private View mTargetView;
private Keyboard mKeyboard;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mKeyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.keyboard);
    mTargetView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.target);
    mTargetView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            showKeyboardWithAnimation();
            return true;
        }
    });

    mKeyboardView = (CustomKeyboardView) findViewById(R.id.keyboard_view);
    mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(mKeyboard);
    mKeyboardView
            .setOnKeyboardActionListener(new BasicOnKeyboardActionListener(
                    this));
}


private void showKeyboardWithAnimation() {
    if (mKeyboardView.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils
                .loadAnimation(KeyboardWidgetTutorialActivity.this,
                        R.anim.slide_in_bottom);
        mKeyboardView.showWithAnimation(animation);
    }
}
```

this is the main xml

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_above="@+id/keyboard_view">
    <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/target"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<it.anddev.tutorial.CustomKeyboardView
    android:id="@+id/keyboard_view" android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"></it.anddev.tutorial.CustomKeyboardView>
```

Comment: you should override **onBackPressed** method like this and hide your keyboard



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

Comment: how to write to slide down ? and how about when i click on the layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Override `onBackPressed()` method in `KeyboardWidgetTutorialActivity` Activity and hide keyboard if its open.

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mKeyboardView.isShown()) {
            mKeyboardView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

**WhiteSpace** Assume your white space is this layout or it could be any layout.

```
        LinearLayout whiteSpace = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.whitespace);
        whiteSpace.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    if (mKeyboardView != null && mKeyboardView.isShown()) {
                        mKeyboardView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: thank that worked but how about the same thing if i click on the layout ?(blank white)

Comment: look at the xml the container which is linear layout within relative layout fill all the layout

Comment: have you tried the second section? can paste your code here.

Comment: the back button worked but the layout thing didn't work

Comment: its the same code with your new codes about the layout but it didn't worked

Comment: try this to hide keyboard when clicked on white space: LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
        container.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                mKeyboardView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                return false;
            }
        });

Comment: it worked like this
 @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        mKeyboardView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return    super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can use `slide_out` animation to slide down for hiding keyboard

**slide_out.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <translate
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" 
     android:fromXDelta="0%p" 
     android:toXDelta="-100%p">
  </translate>
```

and as you are already using hide your view after animation